# DetailTextLabel behaving strangely

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to set the subtitle label on a UITableViewCell. I have a dictionary containing the pairs of titles and subtitles and the list of keys is stored in self.results. However when I run with the following code:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Search Result Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Search Result Cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.resultPairs[[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.resultPairs[cell.textLabel.text]);
```

The subtitle remains blank, but the NSLog prints the correct output. What is going on here? When I set the detailTextLabel to a constant it works fine.

Comment: How did you obtain `cell`?

Comment: I'll edit the question, but title is being set correctly so I know I have the correct cell.

Comment: Make sure that self.resultPairs[[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] is not nil.

Comment: No it is never nil, I print the output each time and I also ran a test to verify that it is never nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that the strings contained allot of initial whitespace, resulting in them being padded out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default cell style does not include a subtitle. If you are using a storyboard, you just need to set the style to Subtitle in Interface Builder.

Comment: No I changed the cell type from the default to subtitle and the prototype cell displays Title and Detail beneath it.

Comment: @stmfunk What did you want it to look like?

Comment: It is supposed to be the title which sets correctly and the contents of self.resultPairs[[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; beneath it. I can set the subtitle if I replace the afore mentioned code with a string

Comment: @stmfunk If the NSLog is working, but the detail text label isn't, you could try doing `cell.detailTextLabel.text=self.resultPairs[cell.textLabel.text]`.

Comment: I have tried doing too I'm afraid. I also tried putting the result in a variable and using it for both NSLog and assignment to no avail

Comment: @stmfunk was the variable actually a string? try `[self.resultPairs[[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] description]`